# Display tkinter fonts

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I have a question regarding python tkinter.

I have made a simple list of all available fonts in tkinter for use in widgets. See script below:

What I would like to do is have the right side of the canvas show an example of the text in the selected font from the list.

Can anyone help me do this? Thanks!

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font

HEIGHT = 563
WIDTH = 900

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas)
scrollbar.place(relx=0.4, relwidth=0.02, relheight=1)

mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in sorted(tkinter.font.families()):
    mylist.insert(END, str(line))

mylist.place(relx=0, relwidth=0.4, relheight=1)
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )

mainloop()
```

Comment: Just create a sample text using `canvas.create_text(...)` and then update its `font` option when a font name in the listbox is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `canvas.config(font=("Yourfont", yoursize))`.

Comment: Hi  @SuspectAverage5. Thanks for your answer. Usually answers with an explanation are more welcomed here. Would you like to update your answer to provide short explanation?